# How to render a collection as succinctly with Haml as with ERB?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, haml

In an ERB view, you can call

```
<%= render @cart.line_items %>
```

and, assuming you have a partial named `_line_item.html.erb` in the `line_items` directory, Rails will take care of the rest.

But I'm having some trouble converting this to something similarly succinct in Haml.

I can get something that works by explicitly calling `.each` on `@cart.line_items` or an equivalent local variable in the partial, but calling `.each` is exactly what I'm trying to avoid.

Here's the partial:

```
%tr
  %td= item.product.title
  %td= item.quantity
  %td.item_price= number_to_currency(item.total_price)
```

From what I've read so far, this looks like it should produce the same behavior:

```
= render 'line_items/line_item', collection: @cart.line_items, as: :item
```

But it's still not working as expected. `item` isn't being passed as a local:

```
undefined local variable or method `item' for #<#<Class:0x007fb3c531aee0>:0x007fb3c3692160>
```

Does Haml have a comparably succinct way to render collections (relative to ERB)? If so, any thoughts as to what I might be missing? Or if there's a better way to do this altogether?

Thanks.

Comment: What is the name of the model class that `@cart.line_items` refers to? The `render` method and how it handles partials is part of Rails, and should work the same with Erb and Haml. If the model is `LineItem` then Rails will create a local variable named `line_item`, not `item` which you are using in the rest of your question. If you change your partial to use `line_item` instead of `item` you can just use `=render @cart.line_items` in your Haml, the same as in Erb.

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for, thanks. I must have lost track of that renaming when I was experimenting. Add an answer and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The render method and how it handles partials is part of Rails, and should work the same with Erb and Haml.

When using `render` to automatically render a collection, as in this case with `render @cart.line_items`, Rails will use the name of the class each entry of the collection to determine both the partial to use and the name of the local variable used in that partial.

In your Erb example Rails is using the partial `_line_item.html.erb`, which suggests that the objects are of type `LineItem` and so Rails will create a local named `line_item`. However in your Haml partial you are using the name `item`, which isn’t being defined hence the error.

Simply change all occurances of `item` to `line_item` in your partial, and you will be able to use

```haml
= render @cart.line_items
```

in your Haml, the same as in Erb.

Answer (score 2):

Try this(mention partial explicitly)

```
= render :partial => 'line_items/line_item', collection: @cart.line_items, as: :item
```